# Not able to lookup JMX jndi in Weblogic managed server

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi, jmx

I am not able to lookup JMX jndi (comp/env/jmx/domainRuntime) in weblogic managed servers ( servers in cluster). Getting below execption. In AdminServer I am able to lookup successfully.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/jmx/domainRuntime 
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:144)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:412)
    at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the Admin Server has direct access to `weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime`. You'll want to access that same jndi via something like the remote example here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/jmx/accessWLS.html

More examples and references:

[access Mbeans on weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821051/access-mbeans-on-weblogic)

http://blog.victorjabur.com/2011/05/16/how-to-access-server-mbean-properties-at-weblogic-11g-using-java/

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/taming-the-jmx-on-weblogic-server.html