# How to identify a weblogic admin server from its managed server?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

The managed server is a remote machine. Given a managed server hostname or ip how can its admin Server be identified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WLST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13715/using_wlst.htm#WLSTG118) for this.

```
>cd %ORACLE_HOME%\oracle_common\common\bin
>wlst
Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

wls:/offline> connect('weblogic', 'dev_password', 't3://dev_host:7011')
Connecting to t3://dev_host:7011 with userid weblogic ...
Successfully connected to managed Server 'soa_server1' that belongs to domain 'dev_domain'.

Warning: An insecure protocol was used to connect to the
server. To ensure on-the-wire security, the SSL port or
Admin port should be used instead.

wls:/dev_domain/serverConfig> serverRuntime()
Location changed to serverRuntime tree. This is a read-only tree with ServerRuntimeMBean as the root.
For more help, use help(serverRuntime)

wls:/dev_domain/serverRuntime> print cmo.adminServerHost
dev_host
wls:/dev_domain/serverRuntime> print cmo.adminServerListenPort
7001
wls:/dev_domain/serverRuntime>
```

Where dev_host:7011 is a managed server and dev_host:7001 is the admin server.

Answer (score 0):

In addition you can look it up with pure java code, JMX, [after](http://danielveselka.blogspot.com/2011/02/connect-to-weblogic-server-using-jmx.html) - [connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821051/access-mbeans-on-weblogic) to the managed server like:

```
String serverName = System.getProperty("weblogic.Name");
ObjectName serverRuntime = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=" + serverName + ",Type=ServerRuntime");

Object adminHostName = server.getAttribute( serverRuntime, "AdminServerHost" );
Object adminPort = server.getAttribute( serverRuntime, "AdminServerListenPort" );

response.getWriter().write("Admin server host and port " + adminHostName + ":" + adminPort );
```